# What is mode in Copy-items powershell and the length values is always 0?

Tags: powershell

```
Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name                                             
----                -------------         ------ ----                                             
-a----        12/6/2020  12:40 AM              0 Test_FULL_20201205_001500.bak       
-a----        12/6/2020  12:40 AM              0 Tetst_FULL_20201206_001500.bak
```

Comment: `Mode` is a formatting-property that shows all the attributes a file on disk has (in the listed output we can see both `.bak` files have the `Archive` attribute set). `Length` 0 means the file is empty

Comment: Thanks for the reply @MathiasR.Jessen.. The actual file size is 2Gb. But why it has to show 0.